Export DBISAM BLOB and TEXT columns
I was recently confronted with the fact that the Borland Database System Utility does not export the TEXT and BLOB columns to a .CSV file.
I searched online, and did not find anything very concrete that was free.
For those who run into a similar situation, here is how I solved it (I am also ready to export the data for you - in which case, send me a message):

Install Delphi 6 (or any version that you have access to)

Place a TDBISAMDatabase object on your form, and set the property Directory to the folder in which you have your DBISAM tables

Place a TDBISAMQuery object on the form, and set the property Database to the name of the TDBISAMDatabase object.

Place a button on the form, and double click it to go the the button's click event. Paste, and adapt the code to the columns in your table, the following code:
var
    myFile : TextFile;
begin
    AssignFile(myFile, 'filename_of_export_data.csv');
    ReWrite(myFile);

    // Use the pipe "|" as column delimiter
    Writeln(myFile,'ID|Genus');  // Specify the column headers here

    QueryMain.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM your_table_name ';
    QueryMain.Open;

    with QueryMain do
    begin
      First;
      while not eof do
      begin
        Writeln(myFile,
            FieldByName('FNId').AsString + '|' +
            QuotedStr(Utf8Encode(StringReplace(FieldByName('Name').AsString, #10#13, '', [rfReplaceAll])))
        );


        Next;
      end;
    end;

CloseFile(myFile);



To export the images, place a another button on the form, double click it to open the button's click event, and paste the following code:
var
  Strm: TFileStream;
begin
        QueryMain.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM your_table_name '; //
        QueryMain.Open;

        with QueryMain do
        begin
          First;
          while not eof do
          begin
            // adapt the following code to the table's image field name
            Strm := TFileStream.Create('C:\Delphi\Delphi Projects\HerbariumExport\Images\image_'+FieldByName('FNId').AsString+'_'+FieldByName('FNHerbariumId').AsString+'.jpg', fmCreate);
            try
              (FieldByName('FNImage') AS TBlobField).SaveToStream(Strm);
            finally
              Strm.Free;
            end;
            Next;
          end;
        end;

The above worked with Delphi version 6. It exported the TEXT columns, and also the images which were stored as BLOB columns
